# When running pynmea2 with sleep the timestamp does not update properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a minimal, testable example of some code I have written to read NMEA data being provided to the UART of the RaspberryPi.  I am running this with `python3`.  I would expect the UTC timestamp to show about a 5 second delta between iterations. However, it is always 1 second.

```
import serial
import io
import pynmea2
import sys
import time

NMEA_data = {}
serial_port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(serial_port, serial_port))

def read_line(tries=0)
    global sio

    try:
        line = sio.readline()
    except Exception:
        if tries < sys.getrecursionlimit():
            return read_line(tries+1)
        else:
            print("Failed to read serial stream.\r\n")

    return line


while True:
    time.sleep(5)

    GGA_message_found = False
    while GGA_message_found is False:
        line = read_line()

        if line.find("GGA") > 0:
            GGA_message_found = True
            NMEA_message = pynmea2.parse(line)

            NMEA_data['UTC_time'] = NMEA_message.timestamp
            print(NMEA_data['UTC_time'])
```

If I let the code run for 60 seconds, I only end up seeing about a 12 second time difference between the first time stamp and the last.  If I then stop the code and immediately re-run it, then the first timestamp shows the correct time.

Additionally, if I remove the `sleep(5)` statement, this appears to automatically update every 1 second.  Although I haven't had an opportunity to measure to see if there is any kind of drift over time.

I'm pretty new to Python, so I am sure that I am doing something wrong here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I don't know what device you're using, but it's probably outputting 1 (or 3 or 5 or whatever) lines per second, and it doesn't know or care how you are reading. If it outputs faster than you read input, a buffer somewhere will eventually start dropping (deleting) messages.

The question is: what are you trying to achieve here? if you only want data every 5s, you should either configure the device to do that, or read read it all and delete every other 4 seconds yourself.
(I am the author of pynmea2, but this question is about IO buffering and not the protocol library)

Comment: @Knio I'm using a Ublox NEO-M8Q for a high altitude balloon project I'm working on with my kids.  I just want to log the location every 30 seconds.  I'm also utilizing Dire Wolf to transmit APRS data over a ham transmitter that I've got on there.  Because both Dire Wolf and my program are going to be consumers of the NMEA messages, I'm going to have to change my methodology to use gpsd rather than the serial library.  Anyway, I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have a lot to learn about how buffering works in the serial library.  I found two methods to solve my problem.

The first is to flush the serial buffer before I attempt the `sio.readline()`:

```
def read_line(tries=0):
    global sio

    # Flush the buffer
    serial_port.reset_input_buffer()

    try:
        line = sio.readline()

...
```

This resulted in an output that I would expect, wherein my UTC data is spaced 5 seconds apart.  That lead me to wonder what would happen if I just closed the serial port while I was sleeping rather than flushing the buffer each time:

```
while True:
    serial_port.close()
    time.sleep(5)
    serial_port.open()

...
```

This also provided me with the output that I would expect.  I am undecided on which path I will take (or whether it is worthwhile to do both).  It's always interesting learning a programming language you're not familiar with!